# Mysql query to get the row which a column have no other values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please see the mysql table structure below.

```
id | user_id | type
-------------------
10 | 234     |  1
11 | 234     |  2
12 | 234     |  3
13 | 300     |  1
14 | 300     |  2
15 | 400     |  2
```

The expected output is since the user_id's 234 and 300 is having types other than 2.

```
id | user_id | type
-------------------
15 | 400     |  1
```

Condition is; I need to get the rows with `type=2` and `type NOT IN (1,3,4)`

Can someone tell me how to write a query like this ?

Comment: Your explanations contradicts your expected output. For example, you tell "I need to get the rows with type=2" but the row in the output has type=1.

Comment: Confused by your expected output. UserId 234 has a type of 2 but also a type of 1 so how does it qualify for type not in (1,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

select * from mytable m where type=2 and not exists(
select * from mytable t where t.type NOT IN (1,3,4)
and m.user_id =t.user_id)

Answer (score 0):

> Condition is; I need to get the rows with type=2 and type NOT IN (1,3,4)

Presumably, you want the last row and not the first row.  If so, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.type in (1, 3, 4)
                 );
```